# Removing row from table

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, asp.net-mvc, row

Good Afternoon, I would like to remove a row from a table , in which when I click on the delete button the whole row would be deleted , the data that should be deleted are Name , Contact number and Age which are also saved in the database so what I would like to achieve is that when the delete button is clicked the data on the website and database will be cleared .Thank you .

I had tried this method , but it only deletes the row on the website and whenever I reload the page , the data will appear again

```
$('.btnDelete').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<td>
    <button href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnDelete" class="btnDelete">Delete</button>
</td>
```

Comment: You need to send a request to your server to delete the data when the button is clicked. AJAX would be ideal. Note that as it stands your question is far too broad and likely to be closed

Comment: Yes you need to ajax call and delete your this row from the database then whenever user reload page it does not apear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write delete functionality in controller like this

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    table1 tableobject = db.table1.Find(id);
    if (tableobject == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(tableobject );
}


[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    table1 tableobject = db.table1.Find(id);
    db.table1.Remove(tableobject);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

in view

```
 $('.btnDelete').on('click', function() {

     $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "@Url.Action("Delete","ControllerName")",
        ajaxasync: true,
        data: { id : $(this).find('td').eq(0).text()  },
        success: function () {

            alert("success");
              $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            // Perform redirect

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.x);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML coding, the button tag contain HREF attribute for link to the "javascript:void(0)" so the click event can perform link to the HYPERLINK location it cannot delete the row from table. SO we link the JAVASCRipt:VOID(0) inside the script.

Script:

```
 $('.btnDelete').on('click', function() { { // <-- changes
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     windows.location = "javascript:void(0);"
     return false;
  });
```

HTML CODING:

```
  <td>
      <button id="btnDelete" class="btnDelete">Delete</button>
   </td>
```

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with the question

Comment: `button` doesn't (by default) have an `href` property, so it was probably originally a `a` that didn't get fixed.  `javascript:void(0)` is a very old method to stop a link from redirecting (which you could also do by making it a button...).